# Flex 4 Application not showing to 100% in Browser

Tags: flex4, browser, resize

```
    Hello I am having issue with showing everything from my flex application. It only shows around of the whole application.

    My application is as such:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"        
                   width="100%" height="100%"
                   xmlns:local="*">

        <mx:ViewStack id="mainstack" width="100%" height="100%" >
            <mx:HBox id="Mod1" width="100%" height="100%" label="Mod1" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle">
                <local:modloader url="Mod1.swf" id="mod1" />
            </mx:HBox>
            <mx:HBox id="Mod2" width="100%" height="100%" label="Mod2" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle">
                <local:modloader url="Mod2.swf" id="mod3"  />
            </mx:HBox>
            <mx:HBox id="Mod3" width="100%" height="100%" label="Mod3" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle">
                <local:modloader url="Mod2.swf" id="mod3"  />
            </mx:HBox>
        </mx:ViewStack>

    </s:Application>



    I also tried putting the following lines in initialize function of Application container but in vain:
            systemManager.stage.scaleMode=StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL (or TO_FIT);
            systemManager.stage.align = StageAlign.TOP;
In fact when using SHOW.ALL..the whole application is as if squeeed to some 50% which makes everything small and this is not nice to view.

    I also modified the index.template.html and have put the width and height to 100% instead to explicit values.

    BUT my application only shows around 70%..the rest(at the bottom) go beyond the screen. (Just note that my screen resolution is 1366 x 768)*

Any bright idea why this does not work??
```

Comment: Once i had this problem .It is due to a Flash resizing add-on on firefox.Maybe, if you have a thing like that , disable that.

Comment: @vettipayyan I am using Internet Explorer..is there any such thing for IE as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the minHeight property of your application to 100 and see if it helps.